# Updating drop down list values in SSRS Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu, parameters, ssrs-2008, sql-delete

I have a problem in my report, the parameter for Students need to be updated as they have left.

At present it shows all list of students(Multi-Value) and picking them along with other parameters will show data in report.

My question  is should I delete the students from database itself or can I restrict them in report parameter so it shows only current enrolled students.

Thanks,
AR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Students is not the Ideal way in terms of maintain Historical data.

You can update the Active status in database for those Students have left. And return the Students whose status is Active in the result set of the SSRS report.

Please find more help [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3453/sql-server-reporting-services-reports-with-optional-query-parameters/).